# Constructing repeated functions

Tags: php, function

I've created the following function to print HTML tags in PHP.

```
function div($attr = [], $child = []) {
    $div = "<div";
    if (is_array($attr)) {
        foreach ($attr as $key => $value) {
            $div .= " " . $key . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }
    $div .= ">";
    if (is_array($child)) {
        foreach ($child as $value) {
            $div .= $value;
        }
    }
    $div .= "</div>";
    return $div;
}

echo div(["class" => "container"], [
        div(["class" => "title"], ["Lorem Ipsum"]])
    ]);
```

Now, I use this function with multiple tags; div, table, tr, td, etc.

For each tag, I declare the function over and over again with little modification in the body. This seems redundant. I want to create a main function which will return the actual function. For example,

```
$div = construct("div");
$tr = construct("div");
```

Of course, PHP is different than JS. In JS, this would work:

```
function construct(tagName) {
    var elm = tagName;
    return function(value) {
        console.log(elm + ": " + value);
    }
}

var div = construct("div");
var tr  = construct("tr");

div("test"); // div: test
tr("test"); // tr: test
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Why not create a generic function which would take the tag name as one of the parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing some more digging, I figured out a way to make it work the JS way. The use of `use` in the examples in [PHP: Closure - Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) did the job.

```
function construct($tag_name = "") {
    return function($attr = [], $child = []) use ($tag_name) {
        $element = "<$tag_name";
        if (is_array($attr)) {
            foreach ($attr as $key => $value) {
                $element .= " " . $key . '="' . $value . '"';
            }
        }
        $element .= ">";
        if (is_string($child)) {
            $element .= $child;
        }
        if (is_array($child)) {
            foreach ($child as $value) {
                $element .= $value;
            }
        }
        $element .= "</$tag_name>";
        return $element;
    };
}

$h2     = construct("h2");
$span   = construct("span");
$div    = construct("div");
$table  = construct("table");
$tr     = construct("tr");
$td     = construct("td");
```

Using a generic function to print the tags seems like a more practical approach, but not that desirable, because the code gets harder to read. Compare the following blocks.

```
while ($row = $albums->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $div(["class" => "album"], [
        $h2([], [$row["album"] . " (" . $row["year"] . ")"]),
        $div(["class" => "album-cover"], [
            img(["src" => "covers/" . $row["cover"]]),
        ]),
        $div(["class" => "songs"], [
            $table([], [
                loop_songs($row["album"]),
            ]),
        ]),
    ]);
}
```

```
while ($row = $albums->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo construct("div", ["class" => "album"], [
        construct("h2", [], [$row["album"] . " (" . $row["year"] . ")"]),
        construct("div", ["class" => "album-cover"], [
            construct("img", ["src" => "covers/" . $row["cover"]]),
        ]),
        construct("div", ["class" => "songs"], [
            construct("table", [], [
                loop_songs($row["album"]),
            ]),
        ]),
    ]);
}
```

First one seems more readable to me.

Answer (score 0):

Similar actually as in js:
Just use the first argument of the function to pass the element type as a string.

```
function construct($elem, $attr = [], $child = []) {
    $out = "<".$elem;
    if (is_array($attr)) {
        foreach ($attr as $key => $value) {
            $out .= " " . $key . '="' . $value . '"';
        }
    }
    $out .= ">";
    if (is_array($child)) {
        foreach ($child as $value) {
            $out .= $value;
        }
    }
    $out .= "</".$elem.">";
    return $out;
}

echo construct("div",["class" => "container"], [
    div(["class" => "title"], ["Lorem Ipsum"]])
 ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the type of tag through a parameter of the function.

```
function ConstrucElement($tag, $attr, $body)
{
    $output = '<' . $tag;

    ....

    $output .= '</' . $tag . '>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would solve the problem at hand:

```
function element($elementName, $attr = [], $child = []) {
    $element = "<" . $elementName;

    ...

    return $element;
}

function div($attr = [], $child = []) {
    return element("div", $attr, $child);
}
```

This has the **additional benefit of enabling element specific validations** etc.: (pseudocode)

```
function a($attr = [], $child = []) {
    if(attr contains no href) return ERROR; 

    return element("div", $attr, $child);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using __callStatic:

So now you can build your HTML with these:

```
Build::div(...)
Build::span(...)
Build::table(...)
```

Like this:

```
<?php

class Build {
    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
        $attr = $arguments[0];
        $child = $arguments[1];

        $div = "<" . $name;

        if (is_array($attr))
            foreach ($attr as $key => $value)
                $div .= " " . $key . '="' . $value . '"';

        $div .= ">";
        if (is_array($child))
            foreach ($child as $value)
                $div .= $value;

        $div .= "</" . $name . ">";
        return $div;
    }
}

echo Build::div(["class" => "container"], [
    Build::span(["class" => "title"], ["Lorem Ipsum"])
]);
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/93d82e4e4579d2):

```
<div class="container"><span class="title">Lorem Ipsum</span></div>
```